# Check if field exists in vuejs and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, vue.js

I'm trying to check with `v-if` when the field exists in MongoDB

I have tried to do this:

```
<div v-if="project.endDate != 'undefined'" class="badge">Test</div>
```

and

```
<div v-if="project.endDate != null" class="badge">Test</div>
```

It didn't work. Can someone help me with that ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't have your database code on the front end. However, the solution you are looking for is `v-if="!project.endDate"`. Also you should checkout the vuejs devtools

Comment: Perfect, it worked perfectly. Thanks for the advise as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `v-if="project.endDate !== undefined"` should help you because undefined is a named object, but when you compare your value to 'undefined', you compare it with a string